# Select an appropriate iOS version from simulators list in XCode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6

I've recently installed `XCode 6.0.1` complete version and it came with default `iOS 8` simulators. My current project is targeted to `iOS 6`, so I did copy old `iOS` simulators into new `XCode` (as I did it before with old versions of `XCodes`). But in the simulators' list I can't distinguish the appropriate `iOS` version. I don't know which of them `iOS 6` or `iOS 8`.

Below paths are where I copied old simulators from and into respectively

> /Applications/Xcode
>   5.1.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
>
> /Applications/Xcode
>   6.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs

[image]

Comment: I have the same effect *without* doing any simulator copying at all, so there is more than one way of getting this.  The accepted answer doesn't help, therefore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow... why did you do that?
The only simulators supported by Xcode 6 are the ones for iOS 7.0, 7.1 & 8.0.

Delete your simulators and go to Xcode > Preferences > Downloads and download all the available simulators.

[image]

Afterwards your simulators list should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I'll try do it. But after converting my project to new XCode how can I support it for iOS 6?

Comment: You can support iOS 6 (although I don't recommend it) by going to your project's target > general > deployment target. If you want to test with an iOS 6 Simulator you must use an older version of Xcode which I don't know where to find.

Comment: After opening the project in new XCode it asks me to convert it to new XCode. If I'll convert it then I can't work with this project in old XCodes where I can use iOS 6. But anyway I think Your answer is the appropriate.

Comment: Well... then you have no other option other than to use iOS 7 as the new minimum supported deployment target. Anyway from my own experience, iOS 6 users are about 0.3% of my users and I have more than 30.000. So I don't think it's worth the hassle.

Comment: Exactly, iOS 8 as of today is already at 46%. If you have to support iOS 6 (which sadly I do at the moment Enterprise) I have to stick with Xcode 5.1.1 and not build for anything newer than iOS 7.

Answer (score 3):

CoreSimulator only supports iOS 7.0 and newer.

Xcode's run destinations will try to disambiguate devices with the same name by using "(OS Version)".  If there are two devices with the same name and OS version, it will use the device's UDID (the long string you are seeing) to disambiguate.  You can clean up your devices (remove duplicates) using the simctl command line argument (run: xcrun simctl help) or the device manager in Xcode.app.

Comment: This is the correct answer for those that didn't mess about copying simulators between Xcode apps.

Comment: You're right. I corrected all the weird names using XCodeMenu->Window->Device after copying simulators between two Xcode apps.