# Application crash after updated to iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios8, nslayoutconstraint

My app crash at start after updating XCode to 6.0.1.
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSLayoutConstraint I get this error at start and I just dont have any clue how to fix it.

Important to say that i'm not using storyboard and also checked every single xib for 'Use Auto Layout' to be unchecked.

Can someone please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have ya tried to re-create Xcode project from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a problem with Auto Layout. Check your storyboard and see if any issues appear there.

Also see what happens if you disable Auto Layout for your storyboard.

UPDATE:
Check if you have UIKit framework linked to your project's target. If not, add it to your Linked Frameworks & Libraries. Set it to required and change your deployment target to minimum iOS 6.

Comment: I'm not using storyboard and also check every single xib for 'Use Auto Layout' to be unchecked. Still the same.

Comment: I had UIKit framework linked against the project, but the problem was that I had to remove it and readd it to the project.

Comment: But now I have another problem: `dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/2BEB9528-175D-4451-B2A5-CDF360F4CB23/app.app/app
  Reason: image not found`

Comment: So, now after you've re-added the UIKit.framework to your project, that error message is gone? For the latest error, set your Social.framework as optional instead of required.

Comment: Yeah, It worked. But now I have another error: `dyld: Symbol not found: _NSFontAttributeName
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/2BEB9528-175D-4451-B2A5-CDF360F4CB23/app.app/app
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
 in /var/mobile/Applications/2BEB9528-175D-4451-B2A5-CDF360F4CB23/app.app/app`

Comment: Change the UIKit.framework from required to optional.

Comment: Now the `_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSLayoutConstraint` error came back.. I just don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: What is your Deployment Target Version?

Comment: That's the problem! Change UIKit.framework back to required and set the deployment target to at least iOS 6.0. NSFontAttributeName was introduced with iOS 6.

Comment: So I cannot develop for iOS5 to iOS8? only iOS6 to iOS8.

Comment: If you want to use NSFontAttributeName, yes. But considering the fact that in Xcode 6 you no longer have an iOS 6 simulator to test on, I would say iOS 7 is the best choice as a minimum. Check this out (also read the comments): http://stackoverflow.com/a/25994472/1641848