# Adding the iOS6.1 simulator to Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode6

I have tried to add the iOS6.1 simulator from the Xcode 4.6.3 package to Xcode 6, but it doesn't show up.

I followed the instructions on this post: [How to Install Older iOS Simulators in XCode 4.2.1 (SDK5.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529572/how-to-install-older-ios-simulators-in-xcode-4-2-1-sdk5-0) to set it up and copied the "iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk" to /Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDK. However it doesn't show up when trying to create a device.

Are there any extra steps I need to take?

[image][image]

Comment: You can't do that in Xcode 6.
Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25994472/1641848

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select the appropriate iOS version from simulators list in XCode 6.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994272/select-the-appropriate-ios-version-from-simulators-list-in-xcode-6-0-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Xcode 5.1 side by side with Xcode 6 to run the iOS 6 simulators. It seems you can't link all the simulators into the same version of Xcode any more.

You can however move apps compiled for one simulator to the other. Just be careful which are i386 and which are 64 bit. See [Install iOS 6 simulator on Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896559/install-ios-6-simulator-on-xcode-6/26049962#26049962)

Comment: Works like a charm. Great work-around. I had to make sure that it compiled for iOS7.1 on iPhone4s like you said then I moved the folder from ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[mydevice]/data/Applications to the old simulator location (~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications).

Comment: The reverse applies too. You can build in Xcode 5.1 for 64 bit, and then move the app into the iPhone6 emulator (noting the app and data parent directories are different for all the ios8 emulators).

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6 does not support simulators older than iOS 7.